# How Should I storage the photo captured by user in android app?

Tags: java, android, database, mvvm

I'd like to make a simple app, to improve my MVVM and room skills. The app gonna have some recipes. App user will enter the title, and description of the recipe, and also can make a photo of it. I'd like to know, what is the best way to store that image? I'm gonna display it on (probably) RecyclerView, so there's can be a couple of them. What will be the best practice to save photos captured by the user?

Comment: Use blob in database.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use blob, You should store the URI of the photo on your database or if you're downloading from an server like Firebase save the url of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just store them as files in the Apps private storage.
 [More on that here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

In your case I guess I would use internal storage to ensure the images are never erased.
To get the location of the internal storage use `context.getFilesDir()`

You could then scan the folder (or some internal folder) to load the images on startup.